# Updating rows in a table with a composite, non-integer primary key?

Tags: peewee

I am using peewee ORM and have a table with a composite, non-integer primary key. The key is composed of a timestamp and an integer foreign key field. An example table and the related model are shown below. I have many tables like this for different data sets I'm working with.

```
class fof2_site_hourly_manual(Base):
    descriptor = TextField(null=True)
    qualifier = TextField(null=True)
    source = ForeignKeyField(db_column='source_id', rel_model=ionosonde)
    valid_time = DateTimeField()
    value = FloatField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'fof2_site_hourly_manual'
        primary_key = CompositeKey('valid_time','source')

class ionosonde(Base):
    name = TextField()
    latitude = FloatField()
    longitude = FloatField()
    instrument_type = TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ionosonde'
```

Now, I can insert rows with no problem using either the save() method of an instance or the class.insert().execute() approach.

However, I can't update rows by any means I've found. Using either save() or class.update().execute() I get 'duplicate primary key' errors. Fine, of course there's a duplicate, that's why I'm trying to update.

It gets worse, I get the same error just trying to examine a row using class.get(). I can read rows using select().

Is this a known limitation in peewee? The docs do state that support for composite primary keys is pretty basic, but don't explicitly state what the limitations are.

Edit: Here are all the things I have tried so far. I have the fields and values of the product I want to insert or update a row for in a dictionary, lets call it data. For inserts:

```
obj = class(**data)
obj.save(force_insert=True)
```

or

```
class.insert(**data).execute()
```

both work. However, if the row already exists (the primary key matches the relevant fields in data) then I've tried

```
obj = class(**data)
obj.save()
```

and

```
class.update(**data).execute()
```

this last one is probably not expected to work (no where clause) but I've included in for completeness in terms of what I've tried. In desperation, I attempted to implement a select, delete then insert loop, but that also fails since:

```
obj = class.get(**data)
```

and

```
obj = class.get_or_create(**data)
```

also give duplicate key errors if the row exists! That one really bakes my noodle, I'm not even trying to write to the DB!

I can read existing data out using

```
query = class.select()
```

and constructing where clauses using the known primary key fields.

Edit:

Ha! Just tried using select() to instantiate an object for a given row, then use delete_instance() to delete it (to then re-insert with the updated data). However, it deleted the entire contents of the table! It really seems as though peewee does not support composite keys, or am I doing something very wrong?

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to issue `update`s?

Comment: Also, what version are you using? Peewee had some bugs related to composite keys which were fixed fairly recently. YOu might try updating your peewee in any case.